# TouchEvent: Detect first / second finger?

Tags: javascript, events, touch, multi-touch

I am drawing into canvas with `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend`. The only problem is using multitouch:

I want to prevent the second finger from drawing. But the second finger also triggers the 3 events.

Is there any way to detect which was first/second?

Comment: Inside of TouchEvent there is an array "touches" which contains both fingers with coordinates. Maybe this is an option?

Comment: Ohhhhhh that could be done... why don't you just do the drawing stuff for touches[0]?

Comment: And what is the exact structure of touches[]?